# Understanding the basics of Matrices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying to do simple matrix transformations but can't seem to get the hang of it. There's a lot of old code on the internet and I'm not sure whats current. Here's the code.

```
               var matrixIntiial = new THREE.Matrix4();
            myObj.matrix.copy( matrixIntiial );
            matrixIntiial.makeTranslation(new THREE.Vector3(-100, 50, -100));
            myObj.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            myObj.applyMatrix( matrixIntiial );
```

When I call myObj.applyMatrix( matrixIntiial ); the object disappears. Also I'm not very clear on how to correctly use the myObj.matrixAutoUpdate = false; and the .updateMatrix();. I know manipulating the matrix directly is for advanced users but I would like to know the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a translation like this:

```
var geometry= new THREE.CircleGeometry(0.05, 10, 0, Math.PI/2);
var translation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(10, 0, 0);
geometry.applyMatrix(translation);
```